# How to a group of reviewers to Azure Dev Ops project to allow code review through Team Explorer in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, team-explorer

I would like to add a code "Reviewers" group to a project in Azure Dev Ops project of which I'm the owner. I've added 3 other users as admin of that project and I want those three to be the code reviewers. However, I can't request a code review of my pending changes. Clicking on Add Reviewer in Team Explorer, shows the following:

**"Reviewer name xxxxxxxx@xxxx.com is not in the list of allowed reviewers."**

Nor does their name show up in the drop down box. However, they can send a code review request to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! this question does not belong to StackOverflow and could be asked at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hi swmdwn, any update for this issue? Just checking in to whether this issue is resolved, if you need further support please feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

> "Reviewer name xxxxxxxx@xxxx.com is not in the list of allowed
>   reviewers."

According to your description you should `restart VS` to reconnect the Azure Devops Service. So that the user data about those three users in local VS can sync with that in web service.

**Description with more details:**

The error `Reviewer xxx is not in the list of allowed reviewers` indicates that someone you choose as reviewer is not even the member of your current organization. Even when you only add those three members to current organization(not add them to Project Admins), they should be selected as reviewers.

Since you've add them to project admins,  I think this issue should result from the VS components' local cache. Such like this:

[image]

A restart and then reconnect to remote repos can resolve this issue.

Hope it helps and if the issue persists, feel free to let me know:)

Comment: Thanks. restarted my system and reconnected. The problem persists.

Comment: @swmdwn Hi friend, what's your specific vs version? VS2017 and 15.x.x? Try updating it to latest 15.9.1x do [vs repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: MS Visual Studio Pro 15.9.18

Comment: @In my test yesterday, even when somebody is only added to current organization and not in that project, it should exist in the drop-list. What's the result if you create a new member in organization and restart vs(For this test, don't need to add it to group or Project Admin), can it occurs in the list?

Comment: Deleted all source control bindings, deleted workspace in VS Studio, created new project in Azure Dev ops, added VS solution to the new project.....problem solved. Still didnt understand where the problem was.

Comment: I think this issue could be related to local cache. Glad to know now it is resolved:)